# save dynamic records in DB using Php, Ajax, JSON

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

I have a table each row contain fields for 1 DB record
table rows are dynamically added and removed
I want to send all text boxes data to a php file using ajax
table is below

```
<table id="tblDmc" frame="box" rules="all" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Subject</th><th>Total Marks</th><th>Obtained</th><th>Class Highest</th><th>Remarks</th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="subRecord">
                <td><input type="text" class="dmcTxt subject"></td>
                <td><input type="number" class="dmcTxt total"></td>
                <td><input type="number" class="dmcTxt obtained"></td>
                <td><input type="number" class="dmcTxt highest"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="dmcTxt remarks"></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="removeRow">x<a></td>
            </tr>  
        </table>
```

Jquery Ajax code

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(){
    var data1 = [];     
    var stdRow = {"s_id":$("#drpClass").val(),"month":$("#drpMonth").val(),"percent":$("#percentage").val(),"grade":$("#grade").val(),"position":$("#position").val(),"curricular":$("#curricular").val()};
    data1.push(stdRow);
    $("#tblDmc .subRecord").each(function(){
        if($(this).find(".subject").val()!="")
        {
            var rowData = {};
            rowData["subject"] =$(this).find(".subject").val();
            rowData["total"] =$(this).find(".total").val();
            rowData["obtained"] =$(this).find(".obtained").val();
            rowData["highest"] =$(this).find(".highest").val();
            rowData["remarks"] =$(this).find(".remarks").val();
            data1.push(rowData);
        }
    });
    //$(this).after(JSON.stringify(data1));
    $.ajax({
        url:'savedmc.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data1),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function(e){
            alert(e);
        }
    });

});
```

JSON.stringify(data1) returns the following

```
[
 {"std_id":"6","month":"4","percent":"77","grade":"1","position":"33","curricular":"abc"},     
 {"subject":"Maths","total":"100","obtained":"99","highest":"100","remarks":"remarks"},   
 {"subject":"Physics","total":"100","obtained":"94","highest":"99","remarks":"emarks"}   
]
```

code in savedmc.php is

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

which returns NULL array()

My question is how to send the above json object/array to php file via ajax,
or any alternative?

Comment: And what is showing on the network tab(press f12 on Chrome)??

Comment: method:post, status:200/ok, type:text/html, and time,size, initiator

Comment: It' doesn't show the json data when you click on the page link in network tab?

Comment: Yes it shows the data there in form data tab, Do I need something different to access that data?

Comment: Can you post a screen capture of the data on the network tab?

Comment: it is: [{"s_id":"6","month":"4","percent":"77","grade":"1","position":"33","curricular":"g g jhgjhgj gjhgj"},{"subject":"Maths","total":"100","obtained":"99","highest":"100","remarks":"remarks"}]:

Answer (score 0):

Replace the ajax call in your JS code with this version:

```
$.ajax({
        url:'savedmc.php',
        type:'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data1),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function(e){
            alert(e);
        }
    });
```

Comment: still not received, it returns null array

Comment: can you check using firebug or chrome console what parameters you are sending using ajax?

Comment: undefined=&undefined=

Comment: json is valid, what else should I test